# Case expression, how to get value from column in Then clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a value for `THEN` from `Mortgage_Type` column if bellow conditions are true.

1. Mortgage_Type and Category are same table and Equipment from another
   table.

> Tables are joining using Item_No. I need to find the Mortgage_Type of
>   each item. I have 20+ Mortgage_Types if Category is main and Equipment
>   is null then should display relevant Mortgage_Type

```
 when SUM (Mortgage_Type)is not null and SUM (Equipment)is null and
    sum(Category) ='M' THEN “value from Mortgage_Type column”
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do as follow :

```
CASE  WHEN Col1 is not null AND Col2 is null AND Col3 = 'M' THEN 'value'
      ...
      ELSE 0 END as Column
```

Or

```
CASE Col1 WHEN <value> THEN '' WHEN <value> THEN '' ELSE <your value>END
```

Answer (score 1):

just give the column name:

```
CASE 
   WHEN (Mortgage_Type)is not null and (Equipment)is null and (Category) ='M' 
    THEN Mortgage_Type
    ELSE <other value>
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL case statement should be used if you want to output a different name for each value of your category, for example:

*

```
CASE 
       WHEN cat=1 THEN 'category one'
       WHEN cat=2 THEN 'category two'
       WHEN cat=3 THEN 'category tree'
       ELSE 'other category'
END
```

*

You could prepare a simple SQL statement with a join on your tables as described hereunder :

```
select A.Mortgage_Type,B.Item_No from table_A A, table_B B where A.Item_No = B.Item_No
and A.Mortgage_Type is not null and B.Equipment is null and A.Category ='M'
```

I do not really understand your "B.equipment is null" condition, is it mandatory? 
In case you do not have any Morgage_type do you want to give a default value?

Answer (score 0):

If your mortgage_type column is not in the table that is using in the join then

--Use this

```
CASE 
   WHEN (Mortgage_Type)is not null and (Equipment)is null and (Category) ='M' 
    THEN (SELECT Mortgage_Type FROM <table_name> WHERE <condition>)
    ELSE <........>
END
```

If mortgate_type column't table exist in the join then

--Use this

```
CASE 
   WHEN (Mortgage_Type)is not null and (Equipment)is null and (Category) ='M' 
    THEN mortgage_type
    ELSE <........>
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say our two tables are Mortgage_details(Item_No,Mortgage_type,category) and Equipment_Details(Item_No,Equipment) assume you own datatypes for the columns.

In order to select the required Mortgage_Type you could have a case statement in below query as :

```
select Item_No,
case when Mortgage_Type is not null and Equipment is null and Category ='M' 
THEN Mortgage_Type
Else Mortgage_Type 
End as Relevent_Mortgage_type,
from Mortgage_details m
join Equipment_details e
on m.Item_no = e.Item_no;
```

Instead of Mortgage_Type in Else You can have any value you want for rows where above conditions are not satisfied.